# Passar txt para xml em java

Tags: java, xml

Olá, estou com um problema em um arquivo txt, preciso passar ordenado para xml, porém esse arquivo txt está ordenado de uma maneira muito estranha.

```
    Nº  Estado Civil    Grau de instrução   Nº de filhos    Sálario Idade   
                    anos    meses
1   solteiro    ensino fundamental      4.00    26  3
2   casado  ensino fundamental  1   4.56    32  10
3   casado  ensino fundamental  2   5.25    36  5
4   solteiro    ensino médio        5.73    20  10
5   solteiro    ensino fundamental      6.26    40  7
6   casado  ensino fundamental  0   6.66    28  0
7   solteiro    ensino fundamental      6.86    41  0
8   solteiro    ensino fundamental      7.39    43  4
9   casado  ensino médio    1   7.59    34  10
10  solteiro    ensino médio        7.44    23  6
11  casado  ensino médio    2   8.12    33  6
12  solteiro    ensino fundamental      8.46    27  11
13  solteiro    ensino médio        8.74    37  5
14  casado  ensino fundamental  3   8.95    44  2
15  casado  ensino médio    0   9.13    30  5
16  solteiro    ensino médio        9.35    38  8
17  casado  ensino médio    1   9.77    31  7
18  casado  ensino fundamental  2   9.80    39  7
19  solteiro    superior        10.53   25  8
20  solteiro    ensino médio        10.76   37  4
21  casado  ensino médio    1   11.06   30  9
22  solteiro    ensino médio        11.59   34  2
23  solteiro    ensino fundamental      12.00   41  0
24  casado  superior    0   12.79   26  1
25  casado  ensino médio    2   13.23   32  5
26  casado  ensino médio    2   13.60   35  0
27  solteiro    ensino fundamental      13.85   46  7
28  casado  ensino médio    0   14.69   29  8
29  casado  ensino médio    5   14.71   40  6
30  casado  ensino médio    2   15.99   35  10
31  solteiro    superior        16.22   31  5
32  casado  ensino médio    1   16.61   36  4
33  casado  superior    3   17.26   43  7
34  solteiro    superior        18.75   33  7
35  casado  ensino médio    2   19.40   48  11
36  casado  superior    3   23.30   42  2
```

Comment: Já tentou alguma coisa? Se sim, poste o código mesmo que esteja incompleto.

Answer (score 2):

Olhando o arquivo deste jeito acredito que ele seja similar a um arquivo CSV, porém utilizando a tabulação como separador, recumendo utilizar a ferramenta OpenCSV, disponivel em http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/, para trocar o separador para tabulação utilize o seguinte construtor.

```
CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader("meu arquivo.txt"), '\t');

while ( (nextLine = reader.readNext()) != null){
            for(String value: nextLine){
               //em value você terá a iteração de 
               //cada coluna em todas as linhas do arquivo.
            }
        }
```